# How could I program a USB port to use its pins like those of an Arduino?

Tags: usb

I'd like to use my usb 2.0 ports on my Lenovo V570 like Arduino pins, and I'm not sure how to program my computer to do that.
My **main** goal is to turn the power to the port on and off (w/ code), thus powering whatever electronics I connect to it. 
My computer runs Windows 7.
I found some ok ideas on this article:
[Controlling voltage supply on usb port using c or any programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858202/controlling-voltage-supply-on-usb-port-using-c-or-any-programming-language)

but I was wondering if anyone had some more ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controlling voltage supply on usb port using c or any programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16858202/controlling-voltage-supply-on-usb-port-using-c-or-any-programming-language)

Comment: I am clearly stating I need more advice.

Comment: Controlling voltage supply on usb port using c or any programming language does not fully answer my question, so therefore my question is not a duplicate (a.k.a. has not been answered).